# Android Studio .cpp inclusion

Tags: android, java-native-interface, header-files

I'm using a recent build of Android Studio (3.0) and I am starting to use native C++ in my code.

Using the default project settings, everything works as desired; however, I have now added dog.h and dog.cpp to test linking.

dog.h

```
#ifndef TESTCPLUSPLUSHEADERTEST_DOG_H
#define TESTCPLUSPLUSHEADERTEST_DOG_H

#include <string>

std::string get_dog();

#endif //TESTCPLUSPLUSHEADERTEST_DOG_H
```

dog.cpp

```
#include "dog.h"

std::string get_dog() {
    return "dog";
}
```

native-lib.cpp

```
#include "dog.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_test_android_testcplusplusheadertest_MainActivity_getDogString(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string dog = get_dog();
    ... [other code]
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library(
         dog
          SHARED
          src/main/cpp/dog.h
          src/main/cpp/dog.cpp
          )

find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       ${log-lib} )

target_link_libraries( dog
                       ${dog} )
```

When I try to run, I get the following error:

```
Error:(25) undefined reference to 'get_dog()'
```

This can be fixed by moving the code from dog.cpp into dog.h.

This same class works perfectly well in Visual Studio.

I guess I am doing something wrong with the way I am including the files, but I can't figure out what it is yet.

Comment: I'm look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html and one difference is that you've added `dog.h` to your `add_library` while in the site shows the header files are included via `include_directories`

Comment: Thank you. That may be it. I am a complete beginner with JNI. I will try that when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Morrison I'm actually still having problems with this. I figured it would be easy to solve with your advice. I am sure I must be doing something really stupid. I have tried putting the .h file in an /include/ directory and using the include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/) and still it isn't working...

Comment: Unfortunately all I can recommend is to go through the codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-cmake/index.html and/or the github example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni and see what differences exist.

Comment: The samples you linked made me think of just grabbing other samples that use a .h and .cpp combination. I should be able to resolve this later today if I have the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to include all the .cpp files in the one add_library call under the same name. You don't need the extra target_link_libraries I had in my original question. Here is the full file:

Updated: CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/dog.cpp
             )

find_library(log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(native-lib
                       ${log-lib} )
```

I'm sure this could have been answered by reading the documentation carefully, but I ended up reading through too much unrelated information.